# Can't reexport the named export 'Name of the module' node_modules/graphql/index.mjs => Vue CLI 3 + Apollo

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

`const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({ defaultClient })`

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  provide: apolloProvider.provide(),
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

> Im having a problem when i integrated ApolloBoost to my Vue CLI 3. it says "Can't reexport the named export 'visitInParallel' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) error  in ../node_modules/graphql/index.mjs"

Following are the different ways I had tried out:
 1. I tried configuring the vue.config.js
 2. using node --experimental-module ../node_modules/graphql/index.mjs

no wonder why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this problem is by installing **vue-cli-plugin-apollo**.

```
npm install vue-cli-plugin-apollo
or
yarn add vue-cli-plugin-apollo
```

Perhaps vue-cli requires **vue-cli-plugin-apollo** to use vue-apollo.